# LM393 window comparator not providing output when used with rail voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, comparator

I have a pretty straightforward window comparator circuit using a 393 dual op amp. The below schematic simulates perfectly and goes HIGH to the 12V rail and LOW to the ground rail during sim. But the breadboard circuit doesn’t work and the outputs don’t rise or fall to the rails no matter what Vin or Vth/Vtl values are. Don’t think it’s a pull-up issue the comparator itself doesn’t seem to operate although it works in the sim.

Note I am using an LM7805 5 volt regulator to keep the threshold voltages in line (lower).

Any obvious thing I’m doing wrong? Thanks!

[image: RTD temperature detector]

Comment: Why the diodes? Why you are not using the pull-ups since the outputs are open collectors?

Comment: I agree with @devnull: Why do you not think it's a pull-up issue?  It sure LOOKS like a pull-up issue.  Since it's an open collector comparator you can wire-or the outputs, no need for the diodes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LM393 is open-collector.

You can wire the comparator outputs together, get rid of the diodes, add a pullup resistor (required) and get rid of the AND gate. The outputs (with pullup) connect directly to the inverter.

As you've shown them, the diodes into a gate input are also a problem (no path for current coming out of the gate input).

Comment: Understood, thank you. Was thinking a gate was needed but see your point.

Answer (score 0):

The LM393 output can't push high, so that is the largest reason it won't work. Add pull-ups to comparator outputs.